# From Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm passing a code from Matlab to Python and I don't know how to emulate `@` functions to Python.
The line in Matlab is `s=fsolve(@spread,0.01)` where `spread` is a function defined after `s` but evaluated on `s`.

I'm new in Matlab so it would be great if somebody could help me.

Comment: `@` here is a way to refer to the function without invoking it. In Python that corresponds to writing the function name, without parentheses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Scipy's fsolve method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) to get the same functionality.

Example:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
s = fsolve(spread, 0.01)
```